# In C: 2 printf output when all I want is one.

Tags: c

This program is supposed to balance an account by asking for original amount then asking what sort of transaction they would like. The printf call is called twice when all I want is one. output: "Enter transaction: Enter transaction: ". Otherwise works fine. code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float amount, old, new;
    char letter;

    printf("Please enter your current balance: ");
    scanf("%f", &old);

    printf("Enter the kind  of transaction you would like: W - withdrawl, D - deposit, F - finished. \n");
    scanf("%c", &letter);

    while (letter != 'F'){

        if (letter == 'D'){
            printf("Amount: ");
            scanf("%f", &amount);
            new = old + amount;
            old = new;
        }

        if (letter == 'W'){
            printf("Amount: ");
            scanf("%f", &amount);
            new = old - amount;
            old = new;
        }

    printf("Enter transaction: ");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    }

    if (letter == 'F')
        printf("Your ending balance is %f.\n", old);

    return 0;
```

}

Would greatly appreciate any insight! Thank you!!

Comment: How many times a week does this problem appear, I wonder?  More than once — this is a much duplicated question.  The difficulty is finding a good version of the question to make into the canonical variant of the problem.

Comment: I guess it's a kind of pitfall in C - it's so natural to just write scanf("%c" ..) and then you have to make a few mistakes like that before realizing what's going on. Not sure if similar thing happens in other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf(" %c", &letter);` instead of `scanf("%c", &letter);`

the original (without space) would interpret Enter as an input.

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You may also be able to solve the issue by clearing the input (previous Enter press) from `stdin` input buffer. Add this line

```
fflush(stdin);
```

before

```
scanf("%c", &letter);
```

However, the solution provided by @artm is recommended, mine might not work depending on platform.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not defined by Standard C. It does different things in different compilers.